# How to remove event listener?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below is my code for event listener

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function (e) {
        if(sessionStorage.token != "abide" )  {
          // call api
        }
});
```

What if I want to remove this event listener, what should I do?

Is the code working like below??

```
window.removeEventListener("before unload");
```

Comment: try  window.removeEventListener("beforeunload"); you have given extra space in your code

Comment: window.removeEventListener("beforeunload") will work

Comment: I believe you also need to reference your function as one of the arguments.

Comment: I just try  window.removeEventListener("before unload"), but it did not work.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

To remove *event listener*, your *event handler function* has to be an external named function, not *anonymous* (you need a reference to that function):

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", functionToRun);

function functionToRun(e){
     if(sessionStorage.token != "abide" ){
        // call api
     }
}
window.removeEventListener("beforeunload",functionToRun);
```

---

**Alternative :** You can also remove it inside the anonymous function call using **[arguments.callee](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee)** which is referencing that anonymous function.
**ex:**

```
var button=document.getElementById('button');

button.addEventListener('click',function(e){

   //some code to be runned       
  this.removeEventListener('click', arguments.callee);

});
```

**Note:** your event handler function has to be fired once, in order to remove it in the above way.

```js
var button = document.getElementById('button');

button.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

  alert('clicked');

  this.removeEventListener('click', arguments.callee);
});
```

```html
<button id="button">click</button>
```

Comment: Does it have to be a named function? Can't you just keep a reference to an anonymous function?

Comment: Confirmed — https://jsfiddle.net/mv9cf7tL/ — the function doesn't have to be named. (Anonymous functions are still best avoided though).

Comment: Also, I think you are not using properly code sample highlighting, `event listener` and `event handler function` are not really code.

Comment: Note that `arguments.callee` won't work in strict mode. Better give that function a name.

Comment: This is not working for me